# kivy, How to display the value(StringProperty) in multithreading by python

Tags: python, kivy

I want to display the value is created by multithreading by kivy.
The value is created by multithreading process in other class. In the root_class i want to display the value.

Detail:
Multithreading process is in calss Aaa(). The method called by multithreading in class Aaa() is in class Ddd(). By kivy language can't display the value in  process running ?

python code

```
class Aaa(BoxLayout):

    def multithread(self):

        ddd = Ddd()
        thread1 = threading.Thread(target=ddd.eee,args=())
        thread1.start()

class Ddd(BoxLayout):
    ff=StringProperty()

    def eee(self):
        self.e = 0
        for _ in range(10):
            self.e += 1
            self.f = self.e * 2
            self.ff = str(self.f)
            time.sleep(3)
class WwwApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Aaa()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WwwApp().run()
```

kivy code

```
<Aaa>:
    id: aaa
    size: 500,500
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        id: button_b
        text: 'exec_root.multithread()'
        size_hint_y: 0.5
        on_press: root.multithread()
    Ddd:
        size_hint_y: 0.5
<Ddd>:
    id: ddd
    size: 500,200
    Label:
        id: label_d
        text: root.ff
```

Thank you for your instruction !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your kivy code creates an instance of `Ddd` as a child of `Aaa`. Then your `multithread` method is creating another instance of `Ddd` and running `eee` of that new instance, So the `Ddd` in your display knows nothing of that. You need to run the `eee` method of the already created `Ddd` instance. Use the id to retrieve it.

So, replace `ddd = Ddd()` in your `multithreaad` method with `ddd = self.ids.ddd`. Also you need to move the id in your kivy code as shown:

```
<Aaa>:
    id: aaa
    size: 500,500
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        id: button_b
        text: 'exec_root.multithread()'
        size_hint_y: 0.5
        on_press: root.multithread()
    Ddd:
        id: ddd
        size_hint_y: 0.5
<Ddd>:
    size: 500,200
    Label:
        id: label_d
        text: root.ff
```